# Adding HTML element values to ArrayList Using JSTL?

Tags: html, jsp, jstl

## **Problem:**

I am trying to figure out a way to iterate over a series of `<li>` elements defined on a JSP page using JSTL. Once done the value of each `li` will be added to an ArrayList in the JSTL.

Is this possible?

## Code

#### JSTL:

JSTL code which will be used to add the HTML elements to the ArrayList

```
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
<% 
    // Java for inserting names for invite into the arraylist
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add(*INPUT from search here!*);
    request.setAttribute("invited", list);
%>
```

#### HTML

Example of the list elements to be added to the ArrayList above -

```
<ul>
     <li> one </li>
     <li> two </li>
     <li> three </li>
</ul>
```

For example, `list.get(0)` would contain 'one'.

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the data? You might be going in the reverse order. JSTL is used to get data from the server and display it in the webpage.

Comment: How are the `<li>` elements created? Are they static (i.e. "hardcoded" in the JSP) or dynamic?

Comment: @JozefChocholacek Yes they are hard coded on the JSP page.

Comment: @DarrenW Well, then the short answer is **no, it's not possible**. The long answer would be you could somehow "hack" it and monitor the content of the `out` Writer, or change the JSP to use something like Nicolas has shown in his answer. But straight "out-of-the-box" is it not possible (AFAIK).